# How to add the shipping zone name to a new column in WooCommerce admin order list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

I want to show the shipping zone name on order overview in WooCommerce.

This shows the order overview

[image]

---

This shows the shipping zone name I want to display

[image]

---

I have read that I can either do it with my own plugin, tried and failed or using a filter in my functions.

I found this filter, to add date to the same orders screen.

- [How do I add a timestamp to the Date column of my WooCommerce Orders screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40034645/how-do-i-add-a-timestamp-to-the-date-column-of-my-woocommerce-orders-screen/49189524#49189524)

How can I adjust this to show shipping zone?

---

My code so far:

```php
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'misha_date_clmn' );
function misha_date_clmn( $column_name ) {
    global $post;
    if( $column_name  == 'order_date' ) {

        echo strtotime( $post->post_date ) . '<br />';

    }

}
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `shipping_zone` is not a meta_key by default
- Partly based on [Get orders shipping items details in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102428/get-orders-shipping-items-details-in-woocommerce-3)
- And [`WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_by()`](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_shipping_zonesget_zone_by/)

So try this instead

```php
// Add a Header
function filter_manage_edit_shop_order_columns( $columns ) {
    // Add new column
    $columns['shipping_zone'] = 'Shipping zone';

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'filter_manage_edit_shop_order_columns', 10, 1 );

// Populate the Column
function action_manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column( $column, $post_id ) {
    // Compare
    if ( $column == 'shipping_zone' ) {
        // Get order
        $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );

        // Iterating through order shipping items
        foreach( $order->get_items( 'shipping' ) as $item_id => $shipping_item_obj ) {
            $shipping_method_instance_id = $shipping_item_obj->get_instance_id(); // The instance ID
        }
        
        // Get zone by instance id
        $shipping_zone = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_by( 'instance_id', $shipping_method_instance_id );
        
        // Get zone name
        $current_zone_name = $shipping_zone->get_zone_name();
        
        if ( ! empty ( $current_zone_name ) ) {
            echo $current_zone_name;    
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'action_manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this filter and action to add custom column in admin panel

```
// Filter to add custom column to custom post types
add_filter('manage_shop_order_posts_columns', "edit_shop_order_columns");

function edit_shop_order_columns($columns) {
    $columns['shipping_zone'] = "Shipping Zone";
    return $columns;
}

// Action to display data in column
add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', "edit_shop_order_columns_data", 10, 2);
function edit_shop_order_columns_data($column, $post_id) {
    $shipping_zone = get_post_meta($post_id, "shipping_zone", true); // Use your logic here to value of shipping zone
    switch ($column) {
        case 'shipping_zone' :
            echo !empty($shipping_zone) ? $shipping_zone : "";
            break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I added the above to my functions.php in my child theme. However, Shipping_Zone has not been added to the table in orders. Do I need to adapt the above? Thank you

Comment: @user3332692 yes try with the same code and replace shipping_zone with your meta key

Comment: also add what did you add in functions.php file